# Using a global catalog in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have multiple domains in my forest, and I'm trying to write a script that will work with any user in the forest, so I'm using a global catalog in my script.

This works to retrieve the data, but when I try and modify the data I'm getting

> Set-ADUser : The server is unwilling to process the request

If I use the domain controller (DC) as the server name, the modification completes as it should. I'd like to avoid writing a switch to set the server name. Is there anything else I can do here?

```
Get-ADUser $user -Server "contoso.local:3268" | %{Set-ADUser -Identity $_.distinguishedname -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -Server "contoso.local:3268"}
```

Comment: What is meant by *"forrest"* in this context?

Comment: @PeterMortensen In Active Directory terminology, a "forest" is a hierarchical collection of mutually trusting domains

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do here. Global catalog ports are read only (for LDAP).

If you want to make sure you find a domain controller that is a global catalog, you can use the following:

```
Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service GlobalCatalog
```

---

Based on your comment, [maybe what you need is `$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx):

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    "*-AD*:Server" = "contoso.local:3268"
}

Get-ADUser $user |
%{Set-ADUser -Identity $_.distinguishedname -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName }
```

Comment: That makes sense for the Set-Aduser part. What I'm trying to do is not create a switch to set the server parameter.  If I don't specify a -server when using set-aduser then it will assume I'm trying to modify a user in my domain which sometimes is true but there will be users in other domains.

Comment: May have spoke too soon, pretty much what you've suggested is setting the GC as the default sever but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @JoeRod I'm a bit confused about which calls to `Set-ADUser` are working and which aren't.

Comment: None work, using $PSDefaultParamerterValues is setting my default server to the LDAP GC which is read only right?  So if I try and do set-aduser anything it fails.

Comment: @JoeRod you said in your question `If I use the DC as the server name the modification completes as it should` so it seemed like _something_ was working. You can discover a DC in a specific domain with `Get-ADDomainController -DomainName`. I mean at some point, if you're in a multi-domain forest and you need to work within different domains, you need to resolve the ambiguity. You might also be able to the AD PSDrive. The AD cmdlets should use whichever domain the current path is using.

Answer (score 0):

For Google searchers who might land here, in the search for a fix for Powerview failing to automatically detect the current domain, forest, domain controller, global catalog... in a correctly domain-joined computer/server.  @briantist answer is the fix we've been looking for.  Specifically two errors encountered.

1. """FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "The server is not operational.""" - occurs when none of the four parameters are supplied to a command (Domain, DomainController, Forest, Server)
2. Even with all these parameters supplied to the command (when available/context-relevant), -ResolveGUIDs (for example) fails with an error like """Error in retrieving forest schema path from Get-Forest""".  This is occurring in composite commands (like adsisearcher or Get-Forest) and lack of ability to supply them arguments directly from the called(ing) command.

## The fix

The fix seems to be to set the values as default parameter values, in the current powershell session.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
     "*:Domain" = "contoso.com"
     "*:Forest" = "contoso.com"
     "*:Server" = "dc12.contoso.com"
     "*:DomainController" = "dc12.contoso.com"
}
```

After this, it is no longer required to set -domain or -domaincontroller (for example) when calling `Get-User` and  `-ResolveGUIDs` works again