# Script to pull users and their managers from AD

Tags: active-directory

I have a script I have written however while it works fine, I ran into a hurdle: Not all my users are in the same domain, and the script is only pulling from one domain.

How would I adjust my script to also pull users from another domain?

Here is my script:

```
Get-Content -Path c:\test\test.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Aduser -Identity $_ -Properties 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'DisplayName', 'Manager' |
        Select-Object `
            'GivenName',
            'Surname',
            'DisplayName',
            @{Name='Manager'; Expression={If ($_.Manager) {(Get-Aduser -Identity $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName} Else {''}}}
    } | Export-Csv -Path C:\test\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What information does your input file have? Does it have the domain? And second, are all the domains under the same forest?

Comment: Good questions! My source file is just a list of usernames I dumped out from one of my applications. There is no domain information in the source file.

Yes all the domains are under the same forest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since all your domains are under the same forest, you can query the Global Catalog instead of the domain controller. The GC will return results for all domains in the forest. Usually, all DC's are also GC's, but each role responds on a different port (3268). So this should be as easy as specifying which port to use.

You can do this by using the `-Server` parameter every time you use `Get-ADUser`, like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Server "example.com:3268" -Properties 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'DisplayName', 'Manager'
```

Where `example.com` is the DNS name of your domain (or the specific name of a DC, if that's what you want).

You could also use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33654753/1202807), which will set the `-Server` parameter for every AD-related cmdlet, without you having to specify it.

The properties you're looking for here are fine, but be aware that not all attributes are replicated to the GC.

These are all the ports that AD uses:

- 389 - The default LDAP port. This is used if you don't specify a port.
- 636 - LDAP over SSL (LDAPS) for encrypted communication.
- 3268 - Global Catalog
- 3269 - GC over SSL